# SQL, case statement not working. The error states that the field POS_Nbr is not aggregated or grouped. Any advice?

Tags: sql, plsql, case, grouping

This is the sql code, the error is under the format line.

```
SELECT
  Store,
  FORMAT("%.0f%%",
          CASE WHEN POS_Nbr in(60,61,62,63)
               THEN (COUNT(DISTINCT POS_Unique_ID)/COUNT (Cal_Day))
               ELSE 0 END) as percent_pure_ACO_mode_at_front_end,
 
 FROM `ca-pr-cda-views.SALES.POS_SALES_ALL` 
   
  GROUP BY  Store
  ORDER BY  Store;
```

Comment: Not sure here but you might want to try, after GROUP BY Store, putting a comma and then percent_pure_ACO_mode_at_front_end (i.e. GROUP BY Store, percent_pure_ACO_mode_at_front_end)

Comment: If you have a GROUP BY then all the columns (whether calculated or not) in your SELECT statement have to either be in your GROUP BY clause or be an aggregate function. Your second column is neither, hence the error. Having an aggregate function (in your case, COUNT) buried in the column definition does not make the whole column aggregated

Comment: this is really helpful information to know going forward! thank you very much. Would the fix be to make the count outside the entire column? rather than nested inside a case?

Comment: You probably need to make your case statement produce numeric values (1 or 0) and then put  a SUM round that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your CASE expresssion - in the below code your construct is commented out (as it errors) and there is a different construct of aggregation with CASE expression...

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "STORE_ID", 60 "POS_NBR", 'B' "POS_ID", SYSDATE-1 "CAL_DAY" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "STORE_ID", 10 "POS_NBR", 'B' "POS_ID", SYSDATE-2 "CAL_DAY" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "STORE_ID", 20 "POS_NBR", 'B' "POS_ID", SYSDATE-3 "CAL_DAY" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "STORE_ID", 61 "POS_NBR", 'A' "POS_ID", SYSDATE   "CAL_DAY" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "STORE_ID", 62 "POS_NBR", 'A' "POS_ID", SYSDATE-1 "CAL_DAY" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "STORE_ID", 63 "POS_NBR", 'A' "POS_ID", SYSDATE-2 "CAL_DAY" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "STORE_ID", 60 "POS_NBR", 'B' "POS_ID", SYSDATE-3 "CAL_DAY" From Dual 
        )
SELECT
  STORE_ID "STORE_ID",
--  CASE WHEN POS_Nbr in(60,61,62,63) THEN (COUNT(DISTINCT POS_Unique_ID)/COUNT (Cal_Day)) ELSE 0 END "PCT"
  Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN POS_NBR Between 60 And 63 THEN POS_ID ELSE '0' END) / Count(CAL_DAY) "PCT"
FROM
    tbl
GROUP BY  STORE_ID
ORDER BY  STORE_ID
/*  R e s u l t
  STORE_ID        PCT
---------- ----------
         1         .6 
         2         .5
*/
```

You should adjust it to your needs and datatypes buut the problem with group by will dissappear if you aggregate values returned by CASE expresion instead of trying to select CASE expression of aggregated values. Regards...